# is there any tool that can generate XSL for a XML?

Tags: xml

i need a tool to generate a XSL for my xml is there any exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used it, but it looks nice. Free and multiplatform.

http://rubyforge.org/projects/xml2xls/

Comment: This project has no files.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like this might be a start: http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html